# Firebase Android-Studio when login email cannot write data into db

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Now, I had finished email login system, but when I login an email account, I can't write data into my database.
When I logout the account it can write data into my database.

Answer (score 0):

Double check your database rules. Make sure your write permission is not
set to null. 
    ".write": "auth != null"

Answer (score 0):

Make write true in firebase 
and
put the write code after  login is success. i.e. inside task is sucessful